# How do I stop looking through binoculars?

Tags: placid-plastic-duck-simulator

I clicked the binoculars on the DLC location *Quacking the Ice*. Now I'm stuck looking through the binoculars and can't figure out how to return to the pool. How do I stop looking through the binoculars?

[image: Looking through binoculars]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>E</kbd> to switch back to the pool view.